# CookieError: llegal key value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

```
Dump Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtoo-ec/1.361220954515344675/libs/handlers.py", line 69, in get
    self.beforeFilter()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtoo-ec/1.361220954515344675/libs/handlers.py", line 51, in beforeFilter
    self.set_track()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtoo-ec/1.361220954515344675/libs/handlers.py", line 99, in set_track
    track_id = self.request.cookies.get("tagtoo_user_track", None)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/webob/__init__.py", line 985, in cookies
    vars = self.str_cookies
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/webob/__init__.py", line 973, in str_cookies
    cookies.load(source)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/Cookie.py", line 619, in load
    self.__ParseString(rawdata)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/Cookie.py", line 650, in __ParseString
    self.__set(K, rval, cval)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/Cookie.py", line 572, in __set
    M.set(key, real_value, coded_value)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/Cookie.py", line 451, in set
    raise CookieError("Illegal key value: %s" % key)
CookieError: Illegal key value: tagtoo_u{er_track
```

I got this error message several times.

The question is

1. the key value I am using is "tagtoo_user_track". where the "tagtoo_u{er_track" come from?
2. this error not always happen. I used the same method in every request. If it is totally wrong, this exception should raise in every request. However, the error message only raise several times.

Is it a bug of google app engine?

## EDIT1

It happened again with another cookie key "tagtoo_user_track".
It looks like the cookie engine doesn't like the "s".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtoo-ec/1.361220954515344675/libs/handlers.py", line 69, in get
    self.beforeFilter()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtoo-ec/1.361220954515344675/libs/handlers.py", line 51, in beforeFilter
    self.set_track()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtoo-ec/1.361220954515344675/libs/handlers.py", line 99, in set_track
    track_id = self.request.cookies.get("tagtoo_user_track", None)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/webob/__init__.py", line 985, in cookies
    vars = self.str_cookies
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/webob/__init__.py", line 973, in str_cookies
    cookies.load(source)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/Cookie.py", line 619, in load
    self.__ParseString(rawdata)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/Cookie.py", line 650, in __ParseString
    self.__set(K, rval, cval)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/Cookie.py", line 572, in __set
    M.set(key, real_value, coded_value)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/Cookie.py", line 451, in set
    raise CookieError("Illegal key value: %s" % key)
CookieError: Illegal key value: tagtoo_user_ses{ion
```

Comment: there is exactly only one function in my code. And you can see in the error message that I called the cookies.get with "tagtoo_user_track" keyword. 
`libs/handlers.py", line 99, in set_track track_id = self.request.cookies.get("tagtoo_user_track", None)`

Comment: have you tried reinstalling your local version of GAE? what happens if you try running it from google's servers instead of locally?

Comment: I am running it from google's servers. the error message is grab from google app engine's log

Comment: That is such a weird error, you can clearly see the key you are calling with in the logs and it *isn't* the same key as the one that's erroring out. Maybe there's an issue with conversion to unicode or something? I'd probably post this on Google's forums/support as a bug.

Comment: Is the program loading cookies from a file? Could the file have the corrupted key values in in, rather than your request? I ask this because your second error is about a key (`tagtoo_user_ses{ion`) that is very different to the key that can be seen getting requested earlier in the traceback (`tagtoo_user_track`). Figure out what `webob` is loading when it does `cookies.load(source)` and I bet you'll find the root cause of your issue.

Comment: The cookies is loaded from request, but I think @Blckknght you are right. I may write some illegal values to someones's cookies previously.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like while there is a format error in the cookie string.
The python 2.5 cookies lib will raise exception, whenever user is using related cookie value or not.

The wrong cookie value can be detect via 
`self.request.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE")`

Therefore, I parse the cookie by hand while exception raised to avoid this issue.